# Graphic issue after clean installation Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: nvidia, login, performance

I have used Ubuntu several times. When I got a new notebook I had no problems with using it. I wanted to switch to another distribution, but changed my mind after 2 weeks. I installed the same 16.04 ISO on same pendrive in the same notebook. Installation done. First boot and...

Everything works so slowly except mouse. Every window and animation is slow. When any layer appears it lags terribly. The funny thing is that Live Ubuntu works perfectly.

I think ok - typically for Linux, I need to waste some hours of my life to fix it. And I did. With no success... Installing other versions of Nvidia drivers didn't help. Only 304 made it work well. Any change of this driver causes a login loop I couldn't fix with the usual solutions.

How can I get it working properly?

- Msi GL 72 6QD
- Ubuntu 16.04 and 17.04 tried

Comment: It is unclear what is the problem. You wrote that the 304 driver works well. Probably your Nvidia adapter is supported only with the 304 driver. You never mentioned your Nvidia device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After clean install of Ubuntu, I switched from `nouveau` driver to proprietary Nvidia. Then I had to edit /boot/grub/grub.cfg and remove `nomodeset` from boot parameters. Everything works, no login loop, everything works perfectly!